# Present perfect or Past simple with "again"?

Tags: past-tense, present-perfect, past-simple

I need your help and explanation.

Which of these sentences is correct?

> Have you forgotten it again?
>
> or
>
> Did you forget it again?

I think the first sentence is correct, since the situation has been repeated several times and it is happening right now.

Am I right?

Comment: Both are correct: _Have you forgotten it again?_ (now, at the present time) _Did you forget it again?_ (then, in the past)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the context/timing as to which would be most suitable but both are grammatically correct.

"Have you forgotten it again?" is present-tense and likely used in the scenario where the act of forgetting is being discussed now.

"Did you forget it again?" is probably likely to be used colloquially, it's more suited to a historic reference - i.e. the act of forgetting is in the past and it's being discussed in the present.